# permuting data and random simulation for chisq test on R

Tags: r, permutation

I am new to R and I am trying to compare a table of observed values with one of expected values and calculate chisq. As a part of my assignment, I need to compare the expected values table with a set of 999 tables that I created using random permutations from the observed values. I need to calculate the chisq value for each table (nsim=999) and then plot a histogram of all chisq values along with the actual chisq from observed data. Here is the data and codes I am using:

```
> survival=table(titanic[,c("CLASS","SURVIVED")])
> survival
      SURVIVED
CLASS   no yes
  1st  122 203
  2nd  167 118
  3rd  528 178
  crew 673 212

> expected=expected(survival) #library(epitools)
> expected
      SURVIVED
CLASS        no       yes
  1st  220.0136 104.98637
  2nd  192.9350  92.06497
  3rd  477.9373 228.06270
  crew 599.1140 285.88596

>nsim=999
>random= rep(survival,nsim)
```

and now I am stuck!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to generate permutations is to use the `sample` command on your `"SURVIVED"` column:

```
sample(titanic[,"SURVIVED"])
```

Will shuffled the `yes/no` labels for that column, then you can repeat this 999 times:

```
replicate(999, {
  permSurvival <- sample(titanic[,"SURVIVED"])
  # Code to measure chi square test goes here
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I did: 

>random=sample(titanic[,"SURVIVED"])

>nsim=999

>replicate(999, {
  permSurvival <- random
  chi2.random <- sum((random - expected)^2/expected)
})

But ended-up with errors

Comment: Probably because you're missing the class data!
Two problems need fixing: 1) `sample` needs to be called _inside_ `replicate`, otherwise every permutation will be the same!
2) create a new permuted survival data.frame: `perm=cbind(titanic[,"CLASS"], sample(titanic[,"SURVIVED"]))`

Now replace `random` with `perm` in your `sum`.

Comment: Thanks so much. I am really new to R so I am confused by what you meant by "Sample needs to be called inside replicate". I guess I am unsure of the syntax. I understand that we need to replicate the random sample 999 times.

Comment: Right, so at the moment, you're executing `sample(titanic[,"SURVIVED"])` once, and storing the results in the variable `random`.  This means that every time you try to measure the `observed - expected`, your permutation will look the same!

Instead, if you save it inside the function `replicate`, each permutation will be different.